# “May your success offend the s*** out of people…”? How can poo be offended?

Tags: meaning, slang

**Edit**: What is the *grammatical* role of "the shit" in this sentence? Is it the direct object of the verb "offend", understood transitively? I think *shit* can't feel hurt, or dislike.

Saw on a blog:

> May your success offend the shit out of people who can’t stand to see you win.

What does *offend* mean here?

I can't find a suitable sense in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offend) which says

> **offend**
> intransitive verb
> **1 a** : to transgress (see TRANSGRESS sense transitive 1) the moral or divine law :  SIN
>   – if it be a sin to covet honor, I am the most *offending* soul alive—William Shakespeare
> **b**: to violate a law or rule : do wrong
>   – *offend* against the law
> **2 a** : to cause difficulty, discomfort, or injury
>   – took off his shoe and removed the *offending* pebble
> **b** : to cause dislike, anger, or vexation
>   –thoughtless words that *offend* needlessly
> **transitive verb**
> **1 a** : VIOLATE, TRANSGRESS
>   *– a contract not offending a statute … might still be in restraint of trade*
> —C. A. Cooke
> **b** : to cause pain to : HURT
>   – tasteless billboards that *offend* the eye
> **2**  **obsolete** : to cause to sin or fall
> **3** : to cause (a person or group) to feel hurt, angry, or upset by something said or done
>   – was *offended* by their language
>   – She carefully worded her comments so as not to *offend* anyone.

Comment: I don't see the difficulty. If these people 'can't stand to see [a certain person] win', obviously they will be 'angry or vexed' if that person does win.

Comment: I am asking the meaning of offend here. Is it correctly used?

Comment: Did you not understand that I was showing you that it means _b 
: to cause dislike, anger, or vexation_ ?

Comment: Perhaps the odd register-mixing of "offend" and the expletive phrase "the shit out of" is confusing the shit out of you?   It is synonymous with "irk the hell out of you", that is, "irk you to an extreme degree".

Comment: @KateBunting did you not notice it is used as a transitive verb?

Comment: Slap on the wrist for confining your definition search to a single dictionary. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/offend#:~:text=(%C9%99%CB%88fend),hint%20of%20prejudice%20offends%20me

Comment: @Tim - everyone can see it is used as a transitive verb.

Comment: @TimR  When I was posting the question, I thought shit can't feel hurt, dislike ...

Comment: You should have said what was puzzling you then. I suspect you wouldn't have received downvotes if you had wondered about the grammatical role of the expletive noun phrase **the shit** in that sentence, rather than questioning the definition. It's an interesting question. Unfortunately a downvote solidifies like a coprolite after only few minutes and there's no way to remove it until the question is edited. I will do so.

Comment: The shit, the hell, the bejesus...

Comment: I modified the title, it's clearer the confusion and I think people will find the Q more interesting. +1 from me!

Answer (score 2):

It's my understanding, possibly mistaken, that contemporary descriptive grammar, when identifying grammatical roles, is deliberately "naive" in the sense that it takes the sentence at face value and doesn't base its analysis on the pragmatic meaning.

So **offend** is transitive here and its direct object is **the shit** and there is a locative adjunct **out of people**.  Pragmatically "people" are the offended entity  but grammatically "the shit" is the offended entity.

The sentence invokes "beat the shit out of someone" which means to thrash them soundly, leaving them battered, bloodied and bruised. So **offend** is being used to mean  "irk, vex, irritate" but to a degree where the irksomeness, vexation, and irritation approaches real suffering.

P.S. I recall a question asking about the phrase "to science the shit out of" a problem from the film *Mars*, though IIRC it was not about the grammatical role of "the shit" but about casting a noun as a transitive verb.

Comment: Hm, my take would be slightly different. I'd say it doesn't have to be so complicated: it's just that "X the shit out of Y" (and similar versions like "the hell out of") is an idiom, with the idiomatic meaning "thoroughly," and an idiomatic construction, in which it inserts itself between the true verb (X) and the true direct object (Y). I would argue that its position doesn't give it a special grammatical role; it's just an insertion. Unless literal scatological humor is intended, I don't think anyone really thinks any shit has been truly offended (let alone scienced!).

Comment: "Just an idiom" and "just an insertion" is not less complicated than a "naive" grammatical parsing of the sentence. It simply dodges the issue.  We agree that nobody (nobody who understands the figurative language) thinks any shit has been offended: the grammatical parsing is not based on the pragmatic meaning and does not yield a pragmatic meaning.

Comment: I guess where I'm coming from is that there is a level of grammatical parsing that is too minute. I have a similar conversation often about music theory. Both grammatical analysis and analysis of music seek to "explain" what happened functionally, and sometimes if we get too granular we're left scratching our heads. Sometimes the best thing is to say "look, this group of words acts together as a phrase" (or "these notes aren't their own chord, just a passing gesture") and not try to "split the atom," so to speak, to assign a role to each word (/note). After all...

Comment: ... it comes down to whether we're analyzing the *meaning* or the structure. Sometimes a single meaning can be expressed either by a single word or by a group acting together. I'm not sure it's the best example, but all that occurs to me at the moment is "the house is *burning*" vs "the house is *on fire*." I would argue that a good grammatical analysis would stop at treating "on fire" as a phrasal, just as it would treat "burning" as one unit, and not treat "on" as a preposition here, suggesting that the house is "located upon fire."

Comment: The opening paragraph of my answer makes that very distinction between meaning and the grammatical analysis of consituents and their roles. There's a lot going on semantically in "offend the shit out of" and a deliberately naive grammatical parse won't ever get at it.